# Populating NSTableView from NSMutableArray at button pressed

Tags: objective-c, macos, uitableview

in an OSX app i'm currently developping to get familiar with obj-c, I want to populate a TableView. After some hours spent reading way too much blog posts, I can't understand how to add a row in my TableView.

Here is what I've done following [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW1):

I have an `NSMutableArray` in my `ViewController`, this `ViewController` implement both interfaces `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate`. And I implement both methodes as indicated in the guide. I also have a button and a tableView. When I click on the button, I fill my array with my own object, that's works great.

But what I want now, is when my array is populated, my tableview is too. I'm aware I need to bind those two in some way, but I have no idea how, can someone give some indication ?

Here is my code for my `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableViewEpisodes.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewEpisodes.dataSource = self;
}

- (IBAction)btRefresh:(id)sender {

    CalendarReader* reader = [[CalendarReader alloc]init];
    self.episodes = [Episode getEpisodeFromEKEvents:[reader getLastMonthEventsForCalendarName:@"TV Shows"]];
    [self.tableViewEpisodes reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.episodes count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColum row:(NSInteger)row {

    // Retrieve to get the @"MyView" from the pool or,
    // if no version is available in the pool, load the Interface Builder version
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

    // Set the stringValue of the cell's text field to the nameArray value at row
    result.textField.stringValue = [self.episodes objectAtIndex:row];

    // Return the result
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bryan-wheeler, I notice a message log when testing his code, and I found out, I was not implementing the correct method: here is my code for my `ViewController` now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableViewEpisodes.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewEpisodes.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    return [self.episodes objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}
```

For beginner like me, you'll also have to implement the `NSCopying` protocol for the class stored in your data source array.

Right now, I only have one element in my TableView and it only show its memory address, but I'll update this answer as soon as I found out how to make it works for future beginner in my case.

EDIT: OK, it works !! My mistake was that: in the `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method, I though I needed to return the Object representing the row given in parameter, but I had to return the one for the AND the cell given in parameter, now I found out, it's pretty obvious, but as a French, I didn't understand the method name correctly. Here is my code now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableViewEpisodes.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewEpisodes.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.episodes count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    if([[aTableColumn title]  isEqual: @"Serie's name"]){
        return [[self.episodes objectAtIndex:rowIndex] seriesName];
    }else if([[aTableColumn title]  isEqual: @"Season number"]){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[self.episodes objectAtIndex:rowIndex] seasonNumber]];
    }else if([[aTableColumn title]  isEqual: @"Episode number"]){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[self.episodes objectAtIndex:rowIndex]episodeNumber]];
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

There is some optimisation to do for sure, feel free to propose. But it's doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are creating a cell view with an identifier which you have not declared, you need to do something like this (assuming you correctly adopted the UITableView protocol in your class):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *Ident = @"Ident";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Ident];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Ident] autorelease];
  }

  [cell.textLabel setText: [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

This is a delegate method for your NSTableView. It is called when the view is loaded so you need to provide a data source at runtime.

Second, I'm assuming you want one section with a number of rows equal to your data array. If this is so, you need to change the delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
```

to:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Finally, keep in mind these above methods populate the ROWS, not the COLUMNS as you have it now. Once you populate your array, you need to invoke the method:

```
[yourTableView reloadData]
```

In order to refresh the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I'm developping an app for OSX and not IOS, so it's not `UITableView` but `NSTableView` (if I'm correct, I'm maybe doing a huge mistake here :) ) But by testing this code, I notice a log message, telling the corrct two methods to implement and now, the error I get is because I don't implement NSCopying in my custom class.

Comment: You have three methods which are required from the NSTableViewDataSource protocol. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDataSource)

Comment: But the third one is only if the user can edit the data in the TableView, which is not my case.